# jQuery(this).val() not returning the value of the selected option

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following script at the end of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#optElem').change(function(){
            jQuery.post('http://example.com', { 'id1': 1, id2 : jQuery(this).val() },
                function(data){
                    jQuery('#abc').html(data.payload); 
                    jQuery('#abc').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
                }, "json");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have an option select field with id 'optElem'. The code above is supposed to be triggered on the change event, and also I want to pass the value of the selected option to the callback handler.

The change event is correctly being triggered and captured by jQuery, however, I am getting an empty value for id2 (this is supposed to be the value of the selected item).

I am using JQuery(this).val() - but that is suprisingly, returning a blank value - anyone knows why?

The option select field in the HTML looks likes this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span id="yearElem">Year: </span><span id="optElem">
            <select>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>                      
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `optElem` is a `<span>`, not a `<select>`.  You are attaching the change event to the span, and as a result, `this` refers to the span when you are inside the function attached to change.

Since `this` is the span, it doesn't have a value associated with it.

Your best bet is to give the `<select>` an id, and attach the change function to it instead.  It makes a lot more sense to have the change event be associated with the `select` rather than a `span`.

Comment: (*Blushing*) - I can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [`val()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) only works on HTML **input** elements (`input`, `select`, `textarea`, `button`). You need to move the `id="optElem"` to the `<select>` element and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change row 4 to this:

```
jQuery('#optElem select').change(function(){
```

This will make you work on the select element inside the #optElement.

(also see the answer by BalusC, you need to work on a select element, not a span)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you need to focus on the "Select" element
by doing this!

```
jQuery('#optElem select:first-child').change(function(){  
            // your codes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a mistake that many of us have made. As @BalusC has stated, jQuery `val()` will only work with input elements(input, select, textarea, button). Because elements like div, span etc. do not have `value` attributes, it seems jQuery has decided to not support this function with the others. Now let's assume we have this ul with some li's:

```
<ul id="tireBrands">
  <li value="Yokohama">Yokohama</li>
  <li value="Michelin">Michelin</li>
  <li value="Continental">Continental</li>
  <li value="Dunlop">Dunlop</li>
</ul>

$('#tireBrands li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());//case 1: Will alert 0;
    alert($(this).attr('value'));//case 2: Will still alert 0;
});
```

So what we need is the value of the `value` attribute. As said earlier, `val()` won't work because of the obvious reason. But why do we still get 0 in the second case. Shouldn't `attr('attributename')` return the actual value of the specified attribute? Haha, the problem is, it seems jquery gets confused when name of the attribute is `value`, that's why it returns 0. If we were to change the above html like this:

```
 <ul id="tireBrands">
  <li value1="Yokohama">Yokohama</li>
  <li value1="Michelin">Michelin</li>
  <li value1="Continental">Continental</li>
  <li value1="Dunlop">Dunlop</li>
</ul>
```

and asked for the value of `value1` attribute, then we would get the actual value.

```
$('#tireBrands li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());//case 1: Will alert 0;
    alert($(this).attr('value1'));//case 2: Will alert "Yokohama or Michelin, whichever one is clicked";
});
```

Finally, here's another setup:

```
 <ul id="tireBrands">
  <li value="1">Yokohama</li>
  <li value="2">Michelin</li>
  <li value="3">Continental</li>
  <li value="4">Dunlop</li>
</ul>
```

Now see what happens:

```
$('#tireBrands li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());//case 1: Will alert 1 or 2 or 3 or 4;
    alert($(this).attr('value'));//case 2: Will also alert 1 or 2 or 3 or 4;
});
```

The difference between the last and the prior 2 html is that, in the last one, value of the `value` attribute is a numeric value, while in the prior ones it's an alphanumeric value. For some reason jQuery is fine when a custom `value` attribute has a numeric value and will behave as if it deals with an input like element. I felt a bit lazy to find out the reason behind it. So if you're curious, go explore the jquery source code. Have a nice scripting.